# Loading Zend Classes Warning and Fatal Error

Tags: php, zend-framework

Output:

```
Popular on Instagram

Warning: require_once(Zend/loader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\Programs\XAMPP\htdocs\hashtag\list1.php on line 7

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/loader.php' (include_path='.;E:\Programs\XAMPP\php\PEAR') in E:\Programs\XAMPP\htdocs\hashtag\list1.php on line 7
```

Code:

```
require_once 'Zend/loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');
```

I've searched a lot but I cannot understand the procedure to solve the issue.

Comment: Did you follow the steps mentioned under "your application needs to be able to access the framework classes" at http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/introduction.installation.html ? If not: do so,